# ASP.Net NPE inside hidden parent container if not asp control

Tags: asp.net

Going back from JSF to ASP.Net I have a problem in following markup:

I get a null pointer exceptin on `this.value` within the panel component. I even called `DataBind()` on the panel itself.

```
<asp:Panel id="pnl" runat="server" visible="<%# this.value != null%>">
    <%= this.value.Foo %>
</asp:Panel>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        return;

    if (this.value == null)
        return;

    this.pnl.DataBind();
}
```

Must i use an asp control always?

Comment: have you tried `<%# this.value.Foo %>` ? ( also Visible {capital}). unless you meant visibility in js

Comment: Thanks, this worked great :) but lower or capital case does not matter in asp.

Comment: The case-insensitive can be changed at future. I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the panel will still be executed even if the panel is not visible. It will not be rendered into the result but it will be executed. I would recommend that you use control properties and set your values via code behind on controls that are not repeating anything

```
<asp:Panel id="pnl" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="literal" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        return;

    if(this.value != null)
    {
       pnl.Visible = true;
       literal.Text = this.value.Foo;
    }
    else
    {
       pnl.Visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: If visbility set on code-behind will markup still be executed?

Comment: @djmj if you set visible false , it wont be output in the generated html

Comment: @djmj it will execute. It will not render any html but the code block will execute.

Comment: Hmm then I would prefer the in markup style from @RoyiNamir answer. Since this keeps view and controller more separated.

Comment: The code behind is NOT a controller. The code behind is part of the view. If you want MVC-like architecture with Web Forms look at the MVP pattern (there is also a framework to help you implement it but it is straightforward to implement without specific framework). The Presenter is the controller but it is not the code behind.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have mistakes here :

- You should do inside :  `<%# this.value.Foo %>`
- Capital letter : `Visible` {capital}).

Comment: This only works if I call `DataBind()` after null checking `this.value` in code-behind (see edited question). So I must still set visibility of panel in code-behind.